# Execution stuck while creating embedded R instance

Tags: r, qt, rinside

I am using RInside to integrate R into a Qt application. Currently, I am trying to run the Qt example present in the RInside package. I am able to build the example but the execution gets stuck while creating an embedded R instance.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "qtdensity.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "First";
    RInside R(argc, argv);          // Execution halts at this point
    qDebug() << "Second";
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtDensity qtdensity(R);     // pass R inst. by reference
    return app.exec();
}
```

The execution is getting stuck while creating the embedded R instance and is giving no errors.

**Working Environment Used**

RInside Package : Release 0.2.14

Linux version : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga)

R : 3.1.1

Rcpp lib : 0.11.4

RInside lib : 0.2.14

Qt : 4.7.4

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

## Update :

Now, I am trying a simpler example inside the rinside_sample0.cpp.

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout << "Starting \n";
RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance
cout << "R instance created\n";

R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

exit(0);
```

}

This code is also getting stuck while running. It is getting stuck at `RInside R(argc, argv);`

Now, when I set R_HOME to my R directory the execution gives me this error:

```
cannot find system Renviron
Fatal error: unable to open the base package
```

Compilation Log :

```
g++ -I/pkg/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/include -I/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/include -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include   rinside_sample0.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/pkg/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/lib -lR -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n -Wl,-rpath,"/pkg/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5"/lib -L/pkg/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/pkg/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack  -L/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib -o rinside_sample0
In file included from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:34,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
                 from rinside_sample0.cpp:10:
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:35: warning: ignoring #pragma push_macro
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:40: warning: ignoring #pragma push_macro
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:45: warning: ignoring #pragma push_macro
In file included from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:34,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
                 from /pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
                 from rinside_sample0.cpp:10:
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:60: warning: ignoring #pragma pop_macro
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:64: warning: ignoring #pragma pop_macro
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:68: warning: ignoring #pragma pop_macro
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In member function ‘void Rcpp::Date::update_tm()’:
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:108: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h: In function ‘Rcpp::Date Rcpp::operator+(const Rcpp::Date&, int)’:
/pkg/.site/pkgs05/OSS-R-/3.1.1/x86_64-linux2.6-glibc2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Date.h:139: warning: converting to ‘time_t’ from ‘double’
```

Comment: Still worked for (on Ubuntu) when I last revisited this a few weeks ago.  You will need to supply more details, and I would suggest trying some of the simpler examples too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi Dirk, I am now trying to run the rinside_sample0 example inside the standard folder and still facing the same problem. I have updated the question with more details. Please, have a look.

Comment: Your build log is only partial. I suspect R may not be built as a shared library, making embedding impossible on that platform.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to build R as a shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Dirk for your suggestion. The `R installation` that I was using was built on `RHEL6` and I was working on `RHEL5`. So, I did a fresh installation of the R package. I installed `R 3.1.3` with the compatible `RInside` and `Rcpp` libraries on my `RHEL5` machine. After the installation fix the examples started running.

**Working Environment Used**

RInside Package : Release 0.2.14

Linux version : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.8 (Tikanga)

R : 3.1.3

Rcpp lib : 0.12.12

RInside lib : 0.2.14

Qt : 4.7.4